# Convert sql query to elasticsearch query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search

Need some help, help me please convert this sql query to elastic search query

```
select city || ',' || state_or_province as facet,
'landing' as facet_type, 2 as rank from listing
where city || ' ' || state_or_province ilike (:query)
and deleted_date is null and status in (:statuses)
```

My params to search, but this query doesn't work

```
 $params = [
            'index' => 'listing',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => [
                            'multi_match' => [
                                'query' => $term,
                                'fields' => ['city', 'state'],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. What information about Elasticsearch queries do you use? Please present how far you got. [Anything in particular with which you are stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Added a question